# Custom Slider (Toggle Slider) not working using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Working on `Jquery` (Toggle Slider).

- On load, the left button should be disabled (currently not working).
- After first click, the right button then left button should be enabled.
- When we get to the last slide, the right button should be disabled. 
  (Currently not working)
- When the slide goes to first position the slide shouldn't move again
- the same for last slide also

Here is my `jQuery` code for reference.

```js
$(".leftBtn").click(function(e) {
  goRight();
});
$(".rightBtn").click(function(e) {
  goLeft();
});


function goRight() { // inner stuff slides left
  var initalLeftMargin = $(".innerLiner").css('margin-left').replace("px", "") * 1;
  var newLeftMargin = (initalLeftMargin - 204); // extra 2 for border
  $(".innerLiner").animate({
    marginLeft: newLeftMargin
  }, 500);
}

function goLeft() { // inner stuff slides right
  var initalLeftMargin = $(".innerLiner").css('margin-left').replace("px", "") * 1;
  var newLeftMargin = (initalLeftMargin + 204); // extra 2 for border
  if (newLeftMargin >= 0){
            $(".leftBtn").css("display", "none");  
         } else {
             $(".leftBtn").css("display", "block");
         }
  $(".innerLiner").animate({
    marginLeft: newLeftMargin
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
* {
  Box-sizing: Border-box
}

.mycontainer {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 204px;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px black solid;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: pink;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="rightBtn" type="button" value="Left">

<div class="mycontainer">

  <div class="innerLiner">
    <span class="box">
      This is box1     
    </span>
    <span class="box">
      This is box2   
    </span>
    <span class="box box2">
      This is box3    
    </span>
  </div>

</div>
<input class="leftBtn" type="button" value="Right">
```

Comment: Your fiddle does not match the code provided in your question.  I also see no attempt on enabling / disabling button in either code; have you tried doing those code yourself or you're just copying and has no clue how to enable/disable button?

Comment: Thanks for replying @Sheepy if you see my code i have a put a condition if(newLeftMargin >= 0)

https://jsfiddle.net/13pn7aup/10/

Comment: See the code now.  You may want to update jsfiddle.  Note that there is no .btn_right or .btn_left in your jsfiddle - only .nextBtn and .backBtn

Comment: sure thanks for pointing out kindly help me on this

Comment: @Sheepy updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are moving to the correct direction.  Here are some tips to fix the code:

1. Move the button update code to a function to make it easy to update and call.
2. Show both buttons by default, and hide the correct one depending on new margin.
3. Call the function with initial margin to disable the correct initial button, before user click anything.

In short,

```
function updateButtons( newLeftMargin ) {
  $(".leftBtn,.rightBtn").show(); // Show both buttons by default
  if ( newLeftMargin >= 0 )
    $(".rightBtn").hide();
  if ( newLeftMargin <= -408 )
    $(".leftBtn").hide();
}
updateButtons(0)
```

Below is a complete snippet.  Note that I took the liability to lightly optimise your other code.

```js
function goRight() { // inner stuff slides left
  var initalLeftMargin = parseInt( $(".innerLiner").css('margin-left') );
  var newLeftMargin = (initalLeftMargin - 204); // extra 2 for border
  updateButtons( newLeftMargin );
  $(".innerLiner").animate({
    marginLeft: newLeftMargin
  }, 500);
}

function goLeft() { // inner stuff slides right
  var initalLeftMargin = parseInt( $(".innerLiner").css('margin-left') );
  var newLeftMargin = (initalLeftMargin + 204); // extra 2 for border
  updateButtons( newLeftMargin );
  $(".innerLiner").animate({
    marginLeft: newLeftMargin
  }, 500);
}

function updateButtons( newLeftMargin ) {
  $(".leftBtn,.rightBtn").show(); // Show both buttons by default
  if ( newLeftMargin >= 0 )
    $(".rightBtn").hide();
  if ( newLeftMargin <= -408 )
    $(".leftBtn").hide();
}
updateButtons(0)

$(".leftBtn").click( goRight );
$(".rightBtn").click( goLeft );
```

```css
* {
  Box-sizing: Border-box
}

.mycontainer {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 204px;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px black solid;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: pink;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="rightBtn" type="button" value="Left">

<div class="mycontainer">

  <div class="innerLiner">
    <span class="box">
      This is box1     
    </span>
    <span class="box">
      This is box2   
    </span>
    <span class="box box2">
      This is box3    
    </span>
  </div>

</div>
<input class="leftBtn" type="button" value="Right">
```